# Previous value incorrectly displayed in my chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

_Hi, I'm puzzled as to why my chart is showing the alert icon for the day before my starting X-axis date ?
The alert itself is correct, but why is it being displayed?
If I opt for a vertical display for this detail label, then it disappears...
Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround? What simple trick could I use? Thanks in advance!
[Here the link of my pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv5UsVxGK-szozzFtJ?e=nr1xr1)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your measure to:

```
SUM Conso CPT Selected A AFF = 
  var st = CALCULATE([Starting x-Axis], REMOVEFILTERS(EDV_View2))
  var ed = CALCULATE([Maximum Selected Date], REMOVEFILTERS(EDV_View2))
  return IF(MIN(EDV_View2[Date_1]) >= st && MAX(EDV_View2[Date_1]) <= ed, [SUM Conso CPT Selected A])
```

Optional: Then you can remove the X-axis Min/Max.

Answer (score 1):

I think now I get your point. The beginning icon actually belongs to 18-Nov-22 bar in the chart. For some settings in your chart, that bar is not showing fully and it's only visible like a thin line. According to your value, that bar should have the alert icon as shown below-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. However, the icon displayed at the beginning of my X-axis corresponds to the previous date on the axis, rather than the intended one.

Comment: Alright, it seems like there were a few small issues with my calculation . Thank you, Sam, for your input! Many thanks to both of you from France!